# ICS Photo editor weird behavior

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cyanogenmod, gallery

I have just installed CyanogenMod and, while testing the Gallery and Photo editor apps, have noticed a very strange behavior. Whenever I try to apply some effects such as Lomo, Documentary among others, the Photo editor applies the effect only to a circle in the center of the image. The problem happens with any image from my gallery, no matter the resolution or the camera (back or front camera).

I have already rebooted the system, and have tried to "clear data" of the app. I have searched all the possible configurations and could not find anything related to this problem.

(The funny thing is that I tried an app called Photo Editor ICS, which is a clone of the original Photo Editor, and it worked fine. But I don't mean to keep using it, I expect that the original app works)

[image: lomo effect applied to the center of the image]

Comment: what version of CM are you referring to?

Comment: CM9.0.0. Running on a Samsumg Galaxy S2

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Aviary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aviary.android.feather&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5hdmlhcnkuYW5kcm9pZC5mZWF0aGVyIl0.) instead. 
It's an excellent photo-editor app with even more features than the default one, and it works for me, even when I flash experimental JB roms where the camera doesn't even work.

This is a strange problem, unique to your device, and you should probably report it on the CM forums.

HTH!

Comment: care to tell everyone else what the linky is about?

Comment: *ahem* OK! Good tip. Thanks for not downvoting.

Comment: I give other people a chance to improve themselves by going "pssstt... what's that about?" ;)

Comment: Aviary seems to be a great app, but... I don't mean to pick any photo editor, I'd like to use the native one. There are many apps out there with great features, but I think it's essential that the native app works fine. Anyway the problem _seems_ to be specific to Samsung Galaxy 2. I have seen in a friend's phone and also there are some people discussing it in XDA forum. In fact it seems to be a problem with the CM9 release, not sure if it can be corrected by a regular user.

Comment: Right, which is precisely what I said--
This is more than likely an issue with the CM9 build for your device. 

Therefore, to immediately get around the issue, as opposed to waiting for a patch from the CM9 team for the SGII--- you can just use Aviary-- since it is fully featured, has the plugin capability, so you can invoke it directly from the Gallery--- etc, etc-- 


Would you like me to edit out the part about Aviary so that "This is a problem with CM9 on the GSII" is the correct answer?